# Delphi WSDL Array

Tags: arrays, delphi, wsdl

I want to write a client to the DHL API with XE10
I imported the WSDL and it generates the correct unit.
https://entwickler.dhl.de/documents/10156/5888530/testsuite_geschaeftskundenversand-api-3.1.4-soapui-project.xml/f5f5bf7c-687c-8a22-d3b7-30a014fc83d9

I can acces to the endpoint with an easy function like getversion.
But when i want to create a shipmentorder, it always gives me an exception.

```
    <ShipmentOrder> 
        <sequenceNumber></sequenceNumber>
        <Shipment>
           <ShipmentDetails>
              <product>V01PAK</product>
              <cis:accountNumber>${#Project#testAccountNumberV01PAK}</cis:accountNumber>
              <customerReference>Ref. 123456</customerReference>
              <shipmentDate>${#Project#testDate}</shipmentDate>
              <costCentre></costCentre>
              <ShipmentItem>



var
  IShipmentorder : Array_Of_ShipmentOrderType;
Begin
    setlength(IShipmentorder,1); 
    IShipmentorder[0] :=   shipmentordertype.create;
    showmessage( IShipmentorder[0].UnitName );  // works fine
    showmessage( IShipmentorder[0].Shipment.UnitName );  // but this object Shipment is not created.
    showmessage( IShipmentorder[0].Shipment.Shipmentdetails.UnitName ); // but this object Shipment is not created.

I can create ervery object in this object IShipmentOrder and then the objects in the next level and so on. But this seems for me no good programming.
```

Do anyone have a sample of an Array_ofTyp, generated by WSDL with some more levels like

```
<Items>
  <Item>
    <Product>
```

and how i can access to Product.

Comment: There is no Delphi version "XE10"!

Comment: What is the exact exception message you get and on which code line?

Comment: You need to create each object. I don’t see why this would not be good programming.